# how to reset pointer of list in for loop after a condition becomes true in python?

Tags: python

```
for r in right:
    if stack.endswith(r):
        stack=stack.replace(r,left[right.index(r)])
```

when the `if` part gets `true` i want `r` to point to starting index of `right`.

suppose `r` is pointing to `3rd element of right` when `if` gets `true` and updates `stack`, then the `for` loop continues from `3rd element of right`. i want to start the `for` loop from `first element of right` whenever `stack` is updated.

how to do it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i want to check all the elements of `right` with `stack` again once the substring of `stack` is replaced.

Comment: That's what your code is doing. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: no. suppose `r` is pointing to `3rd element of right` when `if` gets true and updates `stack`, then the `for` loop continues from `3rd element of right`. i want it to start the `for` loop from `first element of right` whenever `stack` is updated.

Comment: No? I get what you're trying to do with this code, but what *problem* are you trying to solve? There are most likely better ways to approach it.

Comment: Bro, can I borrow your car? - What do you need that for? - I need to push the throttle and steer the wheel. - No, I ment, what do you need it for? - I need it to use my hands to steer the wheel and my foot to push the throttle.

Comment: The question was quite clear, about control statements in python, I do not understand why there are calls to close with "unclear"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cool way is to use an explicit iterator

```
iterator = iter(right)
try:
    while True:
        r = next(iterator)
        if stack.endswith(r):
            stack = stack.replace(r, left[right.index(r)])
            iterator = iter(right)

except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Which in this case looks pretty horrible as there is no "has_next" method for iterators, and the only way to know when to stop is to catch the exception; and for loop would not work here because it stores the reference to its iterator

But really the most idiomatic python in this very exact case is to use the `else` clause of `for` loop to break out the while:

```
# loop forever
while True:
    for r in right:
        if stack.endswith(r):
            stack = stack.replace(r, left[right.index(r)])

            # now break out of the for-loop rerunning while
            break
    # the else is run when all r in right are consumed
    else:
        # this break is not in a for loop; it breaks the while
        break
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first version of your code won't work. `for r in iterator` is going to take its own reference to the iterator, so assigning a new value to the `iterator` variable won't change the loop that's already running.

Comment: Indeed :D ofc it is optimized like that

Comment: thanks @Antti Haapala. the 2nd code is working fine. you saved my day. :D

Comment: Perhaps some comments next to the `break`s would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nest this in a while loop?

```
keepLooping = True

while keepLooping:
    doBreak = False
    for r in right:
        if stack.endswith(r):
            stack=stack.replace(r,left[right.index(r)])
            doBreak = True
            break
    if doBreak:
        break
    keepLooping = False
```

So the process will terminate when right has been searched completely without stack.endswith(r) evaluating as True.

Comment: `continue` is a keyword and cannot be assigned to.

Comment: and for this case there is another keyword, called break

Comment: Oops! Changed the variable name from continue to keepLooping. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to have the `keepLooping = False` line in a `else` clause attached to the `for` loop? Otherwise, the `while` will only run once.

Comment: If the break statement is reached, while keepLooping will evaluate as true and the for loop will evaluate again. Is this incorrect?

Comment: `break` will end the for loop, but then you unconditionally reset `keepLooping` before the condition of the `while` loop is checked. So, the `while` is pointless.

Comment: thanks Blckknght, I edited it.

Comment: the code is still wrong

Answer (score -1):

The main task here is to identify true return and false return. Why not make it sample:

```
While len(right) > 0:
    removedIdx = None

    for r in right:
        if stack.endswith(r):
            removedIdx = right.index[r]
            stack.stack.replace(r, left[removedIdx])
            break

    if removed is not None:
        right.pop(removedIdx)
    else:
        break
```